# RAID10 on SSD drives

Tags: raid, ssd

I can't find information about using SSDs in RAID10. If I want to build RAID10, should I create RAID partition in 80% of total drive size on each drive?

Comment: No. No-one does that.

Answer (score 2):

What you really need to care about is your OS having support for UNMAP and your RAID controller passing UNMAP to your back-end SSDs. If both work fine, you don’t need to worry: SSDs have enough of the reserved space inside themselves.

Comment: That depends totally on the SSD someone buys and someone with not enough knowledge to find information about higher end drives may buy total desktop level crap and b urn them up in 6 months. Happened to me ;)

Answer (score -2):

> I can't find any information about using SSD in RAID10 (for example).

Funny. I find plenty of it.

> I know, that SSD perfomace can degrade, if there is not much empty space on
> it.

That is like saying people die when they sniff powder -the reality is a LOT more complex and depends on a LOT of factors and ther are drives with a REALLY good endurance. Like 5 year sand 5 or 10 complete writes per day. Any reason you stay away from those?

> So, if I want to build RAID10 (for example),

Good.

> should I create raid partition in 80% of total drive size on each drive?

Depends on use case and - you know - how crappy the drives you buy are. When you buy decent drives there is NO reason not to use them. Fully.

Comment: Define “crappy drives” please. Consumer NVMe drives have no power loss protection (PLP) to drive costs down and not so deep memory buffers (because no PLP) affecting performance. Except these two they are no different from Enterprise drives. SLC-to-SLC, MLC-to-MLC compared, of course.

Comment: Check the write endurance of some of the lower cost consumer drives. Let me say it like this: They are perfectly ok for someone using the computer for office work - paperwork, maybe excel. Installing games already challenges it. There is a reason i.e. Samsung has a PRO and an EVO line - the EVO line endurance is really crappy. But saying "BESIDES THIS" is not smart - these ARE the differences And they matter.